# Is the global sections functor on smooth manifolds an embedding?

Tags: differential-geometry

Is the functor $\Gamma:M \mapsto C^{\infty}(M)$ an embedding from the category of smooth manifolds to the (opposite) category of real algebras?

Or equivalently, one has a map of sets $C^{\infty}(M,N) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(C^{\infty}(M),C^{\infty}(N))$. Is this map a bijection?

Comment: What is an embedding of categories? You mean a fully faithful functor?

Answer (score 1):

This is [apparently true](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/embedding+of+smooth+manifolds+into+formal+duals+of+R-algebras). The link gives several references with proofs.